# Regex time validation

Tags: javascript, regex

So i want to make a regular expression to validate times between 12:00 and 22:00 but i cant get my head around making expressions and cant find any examples online that i can just swap out examples of. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `^(1[2-9]|2[0-1]):[0-5][0-9]$` - assuming that `22:00` is exclusive. I'm writing you this because I know it's sometimes a lot easier to understand a new concept by having both the question _and_ the answer and then working out why the answer is what it is, so _please_ don't just copy and paste it and call it a day but actually try to understand how it works by checking the meaning of each of the characters I used and playing with it.

Comment: thanks you. I understand some of the logic just not how to put it all together. so ```1[2-9]``` represents the values 12-19 and ```2[0-1]``` represents the values 20-21. Is there a way that the value 22:00 could be a match but not anything beyond that? If not 21:59 being the maximum value also works. Thank you for the help

Comment: `^((1[2-9]|2[0-1]):[0-5][0-9]|22:00)$`

Comment: What I did there was add another alternative with `|`, but grouped with `()` because the `^` (start of string) and `$` (and of string) should not be part of it.

Comment: To better understand all of this, take a look at https://www.debuggex.com/. Paste the regex into the regex field and enjoy the visual representation.

Comment: Or https://regexr.com/ for a "wordsier" explanation.

Comment: Oh ok so ```|``` is basically a or statement for a expression?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^((1[2-9]|2[0-1]):[0-5][0-9]|22:00)$
```

This is how it works:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`^` and `$` match start and end of string, and they are there to prevent matching also `112:009` for example (which *contains* `12:00`).

`[2-9]` matches numbers between 2 and 9, and `(a|b)` would match either `a` or `b`.

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/X5xgubYHM__irNtf)